# How can I add a method that returns a result?

Tags: java, return

I have been working on these programs.
They don't have any errors but I need to make them return a result in order for them to work properly. More specifically to add a method that returns a result.

The instructions were the following:
*Write a program that is split in to methods at least one of which returns a result*

This is the first program:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed to make Scanner available

public class onlineCalculator {
    
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator();
} //END of main method
    
    // Inserting your loan at the start of the year and the amount paid off
    // and calculates the amount yet to pay with interest
    //
    public static void Calculator(){
        int a;
        int b;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Amount of loan at start of year? ");
        a = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Amount paid off this year? ");
        b = scanner.nextInt();

        int c;
        c= a - b;

        double d;
        final double e;
        d = c * 1.07 * 10.0; 
        e = (int)d / 10.0; 
        
        System.out.println("The new amount owed is (in pounds): " + e);
     
    } //END of Calculator
}
```

This is the second program:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed to make Scanner available

public class BodyAge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CalculateAge();
 
    } // END of main method

    // Inserting age and heart rate and stretch distance 
    //and calculates the body age based on conditions

    public static void CalculateAge() {
 
        int age;
        int heartRate;
        int stretch;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What is your age? "); 

        age = input.nextInt();
 
        System.out.print("What is your heart rate? "); 

        heartRate = input.nextInt();

        if (heartRate <= 62) {
            age -= 5;          // block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
        } else if (62 <= heartRate && heartRate <= 64) {
            age--;            // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is
                              // true
        } else if (65 <= heartRate && heartRate <= 70) {
            age++;           // block of code to be executed if the condition1 and condition2 are false and 
                             // condition3 is true
        } else {
            age += 2;       // block of code to be executed if the condition1 and condition2 and condition3
                            // are false and condition4 is true
        }

        System.out.print("How far can you stretch? "); 

        stretch = input.nextInt();
 
        if (stretch <= 20) {
            age += 4;      // block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
        } else if (20 <= stretch && stretch <= 32) {
            age++;         // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is
                           // true
        } else if (33 <= stretch && stretch <= 37) {
            age = age + 0; // block of code to be executed if the condition1 and condition2 are false and
                           // condition3 is true
        } else {
            age = age + 3; // block of code to be executed if the condition1 and condition2 and condition3
                           // are false and condition4 is true
        }

        System.out.println("Your body's age is " + age);

    }  //END of CalculateAge
}
```

Comment: "*Write a program that is split in to methods at least one of which returns a result*" is hardly an instruction. Are you sure?

Comment: See the `void` keyword in your methods? That's where you would specify that your method is returning a result. You would replace `void` with the primitive type or object type you want to return. `public static int CalculateAge()` for example. From there, you would add a `return` statement where you would end the method and return a value. `return age;` for example. Finally, you would use the returned value. `int age = CalculateAge(); System.out.println("Your body's age is " + age);` in your main method for example.

Comment: Removing the two code parts made your question inconsistent, because it was still referring to them. I undid that.

Comment: Hi onlinegamerunibro. Please explain why you again removed the code parts which your question is referring to. If you want to remove them fine, but please edit the phrasing of your question accordingly. Also, please make sure that your editing does not invaldate existing answer or make them seem weird for referring to "invented" material. I will undo the removal to protect the answers and keep your question consistetn. Please explain before you again add what you have published. Removing large parts of your post is by the way also considered against the terms of agreement and licensing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of one possible way you might consider breaking up a class into using some methods with returns. Let's take your first class for this example. You frequently are taking input from your user.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Amount of loan at start of year? ");
a = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.print("Amount paid off this year? ");
b = scanner.nextInt();
```

This could potentially be broken out into another method for condensed reusability.

```
public static int askForInt(Scanner scanner, String message) {
  System.out.print(message);
  return scanner.nextInt();
}
```

From there you can replace your calls for information with this method. Full example:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed to make Scanner available

public class OnlineCalculator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    calculator();
  } //END of main method

  // Inserting your loan at the start of the year and the amount paid off
  // and calculates the amount yet to pay with interest
  //
  public static void calculator(){
    int a;
    int b;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    a = askForInt(scanner, "Amount of loan at start of year? ");
    b = askForInt(scanner, "Amount paid off this year? ");

    scanner.close();

    int c;
    c= a - b;

    double d;
    final double e;
    d = c * 1.07 * 10.0; 
    e = (int)d / 10.0; 
    
    System.out.println("The new amount owed is (in pounds): " + e);
 
  } //END of Calculator

  public static int askForInt(Scanner scanner, String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
    return scanner.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So how Java will work is the compiler will only read commands from the "main" method. So in the case of the calculator, Java will see that you want to run the calculator method, which has a return type of "void" It goes PUBLIC (meaning other classes can see and interact with it) STATIC (basically meaning that the method belongs to the class itself, not instances of the class) VOID ( this is your return type, meaning after the method is done, what is being put back into main) so if you want a method to return something, you need to change the return type. In the case of your calculator project something like this would split it up into 2 methods one of which returns something:

public class OnlineCalculator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator();
```

} //END of main method

```
// Inserting your loan at the start of the year and the amount paid off
// and calculates the amount yet to pay with interest
//

//this will return an int type
public static int loanDifference(int amountOwed, int amountPaid) {
    int c = amountOwed - amountPaid;
    return c;
}
```

// this will return a double type
public static double newAmountOwed(double d) {

```
     double e = (int)d / 10.0; 
     return e;
}

public static void Calculator(){
    int a;
    int b;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Amount of loan at start of year? ");
    a = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Amount paid off this year? ");
    b = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();

    int c = loanDifference (a, b);


    double d;
    d = c * 1.07 * 10.0; 
    final double e = newAmountOwed(d);
   

    
    System.out.println("The new amount owed is (in pounds): " + e);
 
} //END of Calculator
```

}

seems like they want you to put more code in, but the idea is that they want you to know how to use methods that work together to make something at the end!

use the same idea with the other one!

Comment: This program doesn't work and it gives errors. How can I modify it to work?

Answer (score 1):

First program,
You could for example split your calculate() method into 2 method  and move your int variable "a" and "b" in the main() method

1ST method:

```
void getInput(){
...
}
```

2nd method:

```
int calculateAndreturnResult(int a, int b) {
...
}
```

Finally use those method in the main() and print the result :

```
getInput();
int result = calculateAndreturnResult(){
}

system.out.println(result);
```